# React-router/CSS no hover-style if link is active

Tags: javascript, css, react-router, react-router-v4

I have setup styled navigation with react-router v4. With this code changing style based on hover and active works. However I do want to disable the hover style if I hover over an (react-router) active link. How can I achieve this?

This is my current code:

```
  <div className="App-navbar">
    <NavLink className="inactive" activeClassName="activeLink" exact to="/">
      Home
    </NavLink>
    <NavLink className="inactive" activeClassName="activeLink" to="/about-us">
      About
    </NavLink>
  </div>
```

```css
.App-navbar > a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: rgb(54, 127, 175);
}

.App-navbar > .inactive {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.App-navbar > .activeLink {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(54, 129, 175, 1);
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.App-navbar > a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(54, 129, 175, 0.2);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.App-navbar > a:not(.activeLink):hover {
  background-color: rgba(54, 129, 175, 0.2);
}
```